# What category does the statement "sounds like a plan" fall in?

Tags: idioms, phrases

Is 'sounds like a plan' a phrase or an idiom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "false dichomtomy".  You ask is it a phrase or an idiom. But it may be neither, or it may be both.

In common use, "phrase" means an idiom, proverb, saying or figure-of-speech. By this standard, "sounds like a plan" can be both a phrase and an idiom. In fact in this common usage, every phrase is an idiom and every idiom is a phrase.

In the technical linguistic use a phrase is "a group of words that play a particular role in the syntactical structure of a sentence".  This group of words could be the predicate in a sentence like "It sounds like a plan." And so it is a phrase in this sense too.

According to Wiktionary, an idiom is a group of works whose meaning is not easily understood from the meanings of the individual words.  If the implied meaning is "Let's do the thing that you suggest" then this is an idiom.

So, the answer to the question is "Yes" This is both a phrase (in both senses) and an idiom.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a phrase. It's a sentence in which "It's" has been dropped. The complete form of this sentence is:

It sounds like a plan.

This sentence is an informal way of agreeing with a proposal. It's another way of saying: It sounds like a good idea.